# VS2013 Git source control

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, version-control, repository

I'm using VS2013 with C# code. I want to set up a Git repository so that I can keep track of any changes to my code.

I recently found the 'add to source control' selection and started playing around (not really knowing what I was doing). I tried adding my solution to source control and that didn't work, presumably because I hadn't set up Git and I didn't have a local repository to add the code to. I tried using the Team services section to set up a repository on Git and add the solution to the repository, but I don't think I set it up correctly and I don't think they're linked correctly either.

When ever I try submitting the code, I get this error message:

```
Path 'S:\...\SourceCodeFolder' doesn't point at a valid Git repository or workdir.
```

I think I just need to unbind everything and start again using a step by step instruction that I found.
[How do I add an existing Solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982053/how-do-i-add-an-existing-solution-to-github-from-visual-studio-2013)

How can I unbind all the repositories I may have created and get back to a point where I can start again?

It seems this question has been asked before, but there is no responses as yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268221/how-to-detach-my-project-from-git-source-control-developed-with-vs2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have missed this when trying to find the solution.

It seems that Visual Studio just looks for the presence of the .git directory in the solution folder. Delete that folder it will no longer be considered as a git project.

[Remove Git binding from Visual Studio 2013 solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980389/remove-git-binding-from-visual-studio-2013-solution)